# How to group and get count of rows based on value of one column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of requests with columns RequestType,status .Status column values can be in-progress,complated etc.
I would like to get the list like

```
RequestType  In-Progress  Completed    Total 
Type1         10          5            15
Type2         10          10           20
```

I tried with group by using the 2 columns( RequestType,status) ,but it does not give me the exact result.

Please help me with the sql query.

Thanks in advance
Subin

Comment: Values in `Status` column is fixed or new status can be added in future

Comment: also show your status column over here

Comment: Just show the result which does not match your expectations.

Comment: can be added.But i need to display count of only these 2 statuses.

Comment: You have to use `PIVOT`

Comment: So, put where condition on that 2 status

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using conditional aggrigation:

```
SELECT RequestType,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'In-Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'In-Progress',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'Completed',
       COUNT(Status) As 'Total'
FROM TableName
WHERE Status IN('In-Progress', 'Completed')
GROUP BY RequestType
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PIVOT`

```
select *, [In-Progress]+[Completed] total
from TableName
pivot ( count(status) for status in ([In-Progress], [Completed])) as p
```